# Lighthouse translate report json dynamically

Tags: internationalization, lighthouse, language-translation

I create automated lighthouse reports for some sites. The generated lighthouse.json file is only in english, but I want to support other languages for the custom frontend as well.
e.g displaying an audit or a category in german.
I know I could generate new reports for other languages as well but this would take so much more time and I only need the additional translations, not the scores again.

As far as I know, it is not possible to specify multiple languages the lighthouse report should include right?

I also looked into the lighthouse i18n locales files
https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse/tree/3361b9c97b4db303f0ec7f7e407b8985fbd59b09/shared/localization/locales
but the keys are not working with the final report, they requiere the filenames of the project on build / generate time.

What would be the best approach to get the translations for the report without the need to create all translation files by hand?